# What framework should I use for a Prezi-like desktop app?

Tags: macos, graphics, frameworks, core-graphics, libraries

If I wanted to develop a graphical desktop application that would function in a manner similar to the web-based presentation software Prezi, allowing users to lay down objects on a board, resize them, and zoom in and out, what would be the best framework to use? How would it differ between the Mac and Windows?

I was thinking of using CoreGraphics on the Mac. Not sure what I would use on Windows.

Comment: Core Graphics is a mid-level drawing API. You *will* be using Core Graphics no matter what you use for the user-manipulable objects, unless you use OpenGL (which is relatively *low*-level).